# Create jw player playlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am using jw player to create a website but i can't to read value form variable in .cs file to script in aspx file

in my class file .cs

```
private string temp;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    temp = "var ten= 'Nameofmusic';";
    if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("myScript"))
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(nghe), "myScript", temp, false);
    }
}
```

in my aspx file

```
 <script type="text/javascript" id="flash">
    function getname() {
        var st = ten;
        return st;
    }
    var cssSelector = { 
                            jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
                            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
                       };
    var options = {
        playlistOptions:
                    { 
                        loop: "true",
                        autoPlay: true,
                        enableRemoveControls: true,
                        loopOnPrevious: true,
                        shuffleOnLoop: true
                    },
                    swfPath: "js", supplied: "mp3, oga, m4v" 
                    };
    var names = getname();
    var playlist = [
                    {
                        artist: "Various Artists",
                        title: names,
                        mp3: encodeURI("flash/media/songs/LangTrongTimThuc.mp3"),
                        poster: ("flash/graphics/jplayer_playlister_poster.png")
                    }];
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myplaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);                
        });
</script>
```

why it not run ?
but when i place

```
var names = getname();
```

by

```
var names = "abcd";
```

it was run. who can help me ?
THank every body.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but maybe the script you generated in code behind is output after/below the JS in your aspx files. The the variable will be empty...

Comment: sory,my code is too long, i just take part in this website!
can you help me fix my code ?

Comment: Try what happens when "myScript" appears before your other script.